# Angular 6 authentication

Tags: angular, security

I recently started web development in angular. For authentication, I have seen a lot of online debates for jwt vs cookies. What you guys are using for authentication for angular 6 and if you are using jwt are you storing in local storage, cookies, session storage

Comment: Not sure where you get your research from for JWT and cookies debate, for SPA you'll need to use token based to send it to the web api for every http request via implicit flow.

Comment: cookies are fine if you're hosting from the same domain (i.e. ADFS and WS-Federation uses cookies)

Answer (score 0):

The best for authentication in angular 6 is using jwt authentication token.you have to create authentication service for that.Then you can call the service in your login page.Have a look at the link below of an example of authentication in angular 6.

Please have a look at the example here:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example?file=app%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.ts